# Web service restart at boot time

Tags: python, web-services, amazon-ec2, pyramid

I have a web service deployed on my local machine. Its built on Pyramid web framework. This command starts my server on port 6543.

```
pserve --reload development.ini
```

Okay my question is this. When I reboot my machine, I want my service to start at boot time. It shouldn't require manual intervention to reload and pserve again when the host machine restarts.

Does this task require any startup script?

Can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check out the deployment cookbooks for recipies: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I am trying to deploy my app on an Amazon EC2 instance, and when the machine restarts I should be able to resume my webservice. Something like daemonizing the web service? Any ideas there?

Comment: daemonizing stuff depends on OS. For which you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with EC2, but I've run Pyramid apps on a shared host (Webfaction) and they use a cron script that runs every 20 minutes; if the pyramid service isn't running it starts it up.  I don't have the exact script contents at the moment but I can look it up and add it.

Alternatively, I came across this to run a cron task at startup:

From [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/58801):

> One approach is to add an @reboot cron task:
>
> Running crontab -e will allow you to edit your cron. Adding a line
>   like this to it:
>
> @reboot /path/to/script will execute that script once your computer
>   boots up.